# setSupportActionBar removes menu items

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Apologies if I am not explaining the issue I am having clearly enough.

I have a project that utilizes a MaterialToolbar, it references a menu.xml for its appearances. The menu holds potential icons I wish to use (favourite, delete etc).

In my code, however when initializing `setSupportActionBar()`, it overrides the reference I have set, the icons no longer appear aside from the Navigation icon.

I require `setSupportActionBar()` for my project, is there a way I can retain `setSupportActionBar()` while keeping the appearance of `top_app_bar.xml`? Or at the very least the icon initialized in the menu item?

**activity_main_menu.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"/>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**top_app_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_24dp"
        android:title="test"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
</menu>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_24dp"
        android:title="test"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
</menu>
```

**MainMenu.java**

```
MaterialToolbar topAppBar = findViewById(R.id.topAppBar);
setSupportActionBar(topAppBar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected behaviour. When you set an action bar to an `Activity` it is the role of `Activity` to decide what menu will be displayed.

Here is the documentation and method declaration of `setSupportActionBar` from `appcompat-1.0.0` dependency. You can read it all but I explicitly selected a single sentence from the java-doc and mentioned it below this snippet.

```
/**
 * Set a {@link Toolbar} to act as the {@link ActionBar} for this delegate.
 *
 * <p>When set to a non-null value the {@link #getSupportActionBar()} ()} method will return
 * an {@link ActionBar} object that can be used to control the given toolbar as if it were
 * a traditional window decor action bar. The toolbar's menu will be populated with the
 * Activity's options menu and the navigation button will be wired through the standard
 * {@link android.R.id#home home} menu select action.</p>
 *
 * <p>In order to use a Toolbar within the Activity's window content the application
 * must not request the window feature
 * {@link AppCompatDelegate#FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR}.</p>
 *
 * @param toolbar Toolbar to set as the Activity's action bar, or {@code null} to clear it
 */
public abstract void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar);
```

The emphasis is on this sentence:

```
 * ... The toolbar's menu will be populated with the
 * Activity's options menu and the navigation button will be wired through the standard
 * {@link android.R.id#home home} menu select action ...
```

It means you have to override `onCreateOptionsMenu` method in order to create menu in the activity for the action bar:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.resource_id, menu);
    return true;
}
```

By default, if you do not override this method, the menu will be populated

> ... with standard system menu items.

Source of the quote (note, I removed explanations from java-doc of `onCreateOptionsMenu` that are irrelevant to this issue):

```
/**
 * Initialize the contents of the Activity's standard options menu.  You
 * should place your menu items in to <var>menu</var>.
 *
 * <p>This is only called once, the first time the options menu is
 * displayed.
 *
 * <p>The default implementation populates the menu with standard system
 * menu items. 
 *
 * @param menu The options menu in which you place your items.
 *
 * @return You must return true for the menu to be displayed;
 *         if you return false it will not be shown.
 */
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (mParent != null) {
        return mParent.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This appears to have solved my question, Thank you. I appreciate it.